# Описание сайта meta description

Tags: html, seo

Начинаю знакомиться с seo. Первый простой шаг: работа с Google. В поиске всё индексируется и сайт находится, но описание страницы почему-то не берётся из meta description, а берётся из содержимого сайта. Собственно сделал самый примитивный шаблон за несколько минут и записал в meta description максимально соответствующее содержимому сайта описание. Наверное, что-то сделал не так и допустил какую-то ошибку.

Вот мета-тег:

```
<meta name="description" content="Real gangsta shop is a site for real gangsters">
```

А вот сам [сайт](https://mysite-simple-test.mcdir.ru/).

ps: знаю, что содержимое сайта идиотское;)

Comment: description и keywords уже много лет игнорируются поисковиками именно из-за SEO - туда писали всякий хлам для продвижения. Просто делайте неидиотское содержимое ;)

Comment: Получается, что в этих тегах вообще нет смысла.

Comment: Хотя, когда я гуглю имя одного из своих сайтов, гугл таки высвечивает description для главной страницы. Но вот других случаев влияния description я не припомню

Comment: Видимо поисковики сами определяют соответствие мета-тегов содержимому. И, судя по всему, не очень успешно.

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать предположить, что у description низкий приоритет. Вот у вас на странице есть семантический тег <section> — возможно, гугл считает, что его содержимое важнее, чем содержимое description (но я ненастоящий сеошник, просто предполагаю)

Comment: Интересное предположение, надо потестировать на различных html-разметках. Жаль, что на индексацию поисковиками уходит приличное время.

Answer (score 1):

Гугл довольно определенно высказывается о мета описании в **[Руководство по поисковой оптимизации для начинающих](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=ru)** :

> **Используйте мета-теги description**
>
> Мета-тег описания (description) на странице помогает Google и другим
>   поисковым системам понять ее содержание.

и далее:

> **Преимущества мета-тегов описания**
>
> Мета-теги description важны, поскольку Google может использовать их как
>   как описание ваших страниц. Также Google может выбирать в качестве
>   описания фрагмент видимого текста страницы, если он соответствует
>   поисковому запросу. Рекомендуется добавлять мета-теги описания на все
>   страницы на случай, если Google не сможет найти отрывок текста,
>   соответствующий поисковому запросу.

В вашем случает отказ Гугл от вашего мета описания может означать что это описание не соответствует главному содержания веб-страницы. Возможно там надо использовать что-то похожее на следующее: "***The authorized online store for real gangsters. You can buy here the brass knuckles, the gun or the cadillac and other products for gangsters***".

Comment: Обязательно попробую поэкспериментировать с текстовым содержимым сайтов  и различными описаниями. Скорее всего да, гугл не считает описание соответствующим для содержимого сайта.